# Exception when trying to insert (upload) an image to Richtext control (aka CKEditor)

Tags: ckeditor, xpages, lotus-domino

Since tonight I get this exception when trying to add (upload) an image in the CKEditor on an XPage. This worked fine before. I didn't change anything (server, no fixpack/IF installed etc.). I get this on several versions of 9.0.1 (with FP1, FP2). The form of the document I have in edit mode associates an XPage (I load the document via the %24%24OpenDominoDocument.xsp URL). The servers are freshly started and I also did a "project > clean".
This is the error in the .log file when I hit the "upload" button (FP1) / after selecting the image from the disk (FP2 does fire the upload event automatically):

```
20.02.15 02:22: Exception Thrown
Context Path: /hp_v2.nsf
com.ibm.xsp.FacesExceptionEx: Unable to get document page name for null
at com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.DominoDocumentPageTransformer.transformPageName(DominoDocumentPageTransformer.java:69)
at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.convertVirtualPage(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:690)
at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl._createViewRoot(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:490)
at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.createViewRoot(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:567)
at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.doCreateView(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:142)
at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerEx.createView(ViewHandlerEx.java:90)
at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl._restoreView(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:395)
at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.restoreView(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:358)
at com.ibm.xsp.controller.FacesControllerImpl.restoreView(FacesControllerImpl.java:220)
at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceAjaxPartialView(FacesServletEx.java:194)
at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceAjaxPartialViewSync(FacesServletEx.java:176)
at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceView(FacesServletEx.java:155)
at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:160)
at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(FacesServletEx.java:138)
at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(DesignerFacesServlet.java:103)
at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:576)
at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(NSFComponentModule.java:1335)
at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:853)
at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(ComponentModule.java:796)
at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(ComponentModule.java:565)
at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(NSFComponentModule.java:1319)
at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(NSFService.java:662)
at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(NSFService.java:482)
at org.openntf.domino.xsp.adapter.OpenntfHttpService.doService(OpenntfHttpService.java:89)
at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:350)
at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:306)
at com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:272)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.DominoUtils.isUNID(DominoUtils.java:435)
at com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.DominoUtils.getDocumentById(DominoUtils.java:455)
at com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.DominoUtils.getDocumentById(DominoUtils.java:472)
at com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.DominoDocumentPageTransformer.transformPageName(DominoDocumentPageTransformer.java:51)
... 26 more
```

I never saw that - any ideas what might cause this behavior?

**Interesting fact:** when I open the document by opening the corresponding .xsp (e.g. adminEvent.xsp) instead of using %24%24OpenDominoDocument.xsp it works, so I assume for some reason the form property is not recognized.

Answer (score 0):

I had this before. Are you using `requestParamPrefix`?

The problem I had was that when I use a non-standard request parameter name (other than `documentId`, the standard `$$OpenDominoDocument.xsp` page resolver fails with this error message. It looks for an explicit `documentId` query parameter and tries to resolve that as a universal id, in order to determine which XPages should be used to open.

Comment: Neither nor, Serdar. Not using that prefix property and my URL looks quite "normal", like %24%24OpenDominoDocument.xsp?documentId=9FA63726A6FB5314C1257DEB006137E7&action=editDocument

Comment: Interesting. Can you also check if view state is disabled (`nostate`)?

Comment: I didn't set any viewState property so it works with the default behavior.

Comment: I did some testing and saw that subsequent calls to `$$OpenDominoDocument.xsp` could generate the same error, in case they don't match with an existing state. That's why I thought view state might be disabled.

Comment: Did you test if the same problem repeats for a partial refresh, instead of inserting an image?

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a bit late. I had the same problem, could not insert image in my rich text control, got the error "undefined". Problem was that my rich text control was not linked to a domino document data source. I added the document data source to my xpage, linked my rich text control to the data source and the rich text field on my document and it works perfectly. Hope it helps someone.